# "No module named" error after installing the module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I've installed the [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) using `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`. I've imported the *telebot* package to use the API.

But when I want to run my program, it says: No module named 'telebot'. The entire error message is:

```
(...file path...) Telegram Bot>CertificateBot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
(...file path...) \CertificateBot.py", line 1, in <module>
import telebot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'
```

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: Run `pip -V` and `python -V` and check whether the python version matches. If not, install the package for the correct Python version.

Comment: @shamilpython Windows 10

Comment: hmm. try @hoefling solution then.

Comment: Are you sure you installed it for Python 3, and not maybe for Python 2? Have you tried using `pip3` instead of `pip`?

Comment: @tobias_k using pip3, it says: 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @hoefling  python -V ----> Python 3.6.3 / pip -V ----> pip 9.0.1... (python 3.6)

Comment: Looks good; can you add a [mcve] so we can reproduce it on our machines?

Comment: btw. pip is allready on version 18

Answer (score 2):

Try `python3 -m pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`
Probably pip installs the module to a different python version.

Comment: 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
    
pip3 uninstall telebot
    
pip3 uninstall PyTelegramBotAPI

pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
    
pip3 install --upgrade pyTelegramBotAPI
```